# Not going anywhere fast

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I’m an island domain, and where strong drink is found,
>   Yet I’m baffled by cricket, and silent (no sound).
>
> I’m a person of faith, and devoid of all strife;
>   I am "the Way”, and one’s stance after life.
>
> I’m a small, weighty rock, and unchanged from the past.
>   I am not going anywhere fast!

**What am I?**

<sub>*(The answer is one word.  Please explain all lines of the riddle in your reasoning.)*</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My position is you are a

> standstill - clued by **st** (abbreviation) + **and** + **still**

I’m an island domain, and where strong drink is found,

> st (Internet domain for São Tomé and Príncipe) + and + a vessel for distilling spirits

Yet I’m baffled by cricket, and silent (no sound).

> st (abbrev. for stumped in cricket) + and + uttering no sound

I’m a person of faith, and devoid of all strife;

> St (Saint) + and + calm/peaceful

I am "the Way”, and one’s stance after life.

> St (Street for the Way) + and + without motion

I’m a small, weighty rock, and unchanged from the past.

> st (the measure of weight) + and +  unchanging

I am not going anywhere fast!

> You are staying stationary.

Comment: Spot on! A perfect answer - you truly are the Riddle King... Checkmark incoming :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are:

> **NIRVANA**

*I’m an island domain, and where strong drink is found,*

> There is something called **Nirvana Island: The Last 47 Days**. There is also a **Nirvana cocktail**.

*Yet I’m baffled by cricket, and silent (no sound).*

> There's a [**Nirvana Cricket Club**](https://nirvanacricketclub.in/). The band **Nirvana** disbanded after Kurt Cobain died.

*I’m a person of faith, and devoid of all strife;*

> In some Buddhist traditions, **nirvana** is the achievement of stillness/nothingness.

*I am "the Way”, and one’s stance after life.*

> The Middle Way is a description of the Noble Eightfold Path, which you follow to achieve **nirvana** in the afterlife.

*I’m a small, weighty rock, and unchanged from the past.*

> **Nirvana** is the name of a rock band. The band dissolved, so its music remains unchanged.

*I am not going anywhere fast!*

> **Nirvana** is a sort of transcendent state where you are infinitely freed from the pushes/pulls of everyday life. Therefore, once you achieve nirvana, you won't be going anywhere.

Comment: This is a nice attempt :) But it's not right... Some of the references you mention are quite obscure (e.g. the movie and the cocktail), but everything the riddle actually alludes to is better known. There is also much more wordplay involved. But still - nice try!